# Ubuntu Karmic Koala and Apple Mac Pro 8-core

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, mac

Does anyone have experience with installing/running Ubuntu (Karmic Koala) on a Mac Pro 8-core desktop?

Does it install smoothly?  Are there issues to be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro) on the wiki lists the status of various parts of Ubuntu under the Mac Pro. Looks like it's mostly smooth sailing except for a bit of manual work on the video and audio driver side.

There's also a [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhYx5d47Uh8) of 9.10 running smoothly on a Mac Pro. Looks like you should be alright.

Comment: That video shows Ubuntu running as a virtual machine - you can run pretty much any OS like that (including Windows 3.11), it's not the same as running it on the actual machine.. Regardless, +1 for the Ubuntu Wiki link

Answer (score 0):

I have a mac pro with 32gb ram and 8 cores. I installed Ubuntu 8.0 and it worked liked a dream! Just don't forget to install it as 64 bit!